# Android App developement and Error in monodevelop

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I have written a hello world app in monodevelop(version 3.05) and trying to run it on  emulator. Program is compiled successfully but when I try to Run it it gives following error.

```
   Detecting installed packages


   Installing shared runtime


   Deployment failed. Internal error
```

I have installed all prerequisites.

```
    1. mono for Android
     2. mono framework
      3. gtk#
       4. Android SDK
```

[image: I install all packages through SDK Manager]

Following is code.

```
 using System;

  using Android.App;
  using Android.Content;
  using Android.Runtime;
  using Android.Views;
  using Android.Widget;
  using Android.OS;

   namespace  myAndroid
    {
[Activity (Label = "myAndroid", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
        };
    }
    }
         }
```

Edit:
.Net 2.0 .Net 4.0 visual studio 2010 express are already installed on my computer.
I run visual studio 2005 as administrator on windows 7 but monodevelop does not give me this option to run as administrator if this a problem related to permission rights.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this in VS2010 and VS2012 as well and the main reason for this is, when the the project is not set to deploy in the Solution properties.

[image: Property window for Solution]

If that deploy flag is removed you will run into that issue.

Comment: I am using monodevelop as add-in is not available for vs 2010 express.I have checked deploy option and run the program but still no luck.